# Existence of two relative branches Abstract algebra and Linear Algebra.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus

What exactly is the reason behind the emergence of two areas Abstract Algebra and Linear Algebra. Infact, both comes under Algebra.

I understand that abstract algebra deal with abstract algebraic structures, but how vector spaces are not offenly comes under this topic.

Comment: Well, yes, linear algebra might be viewed as a 'subarea' of Abstract Algebra.

Comment: @ Berci So, the special area Linear algebra is emerged for the purpose of typical study?

Comment: Just a guess (however, based on nearly 5 decades of much library browsing and interest in mathematical literature), but I suspect the (U.S.) undergraduate level courses in abstract algebra evolved from earlier courses in the theory of equations, and (U.S.) undergraduate courses in linear algebra evolved from earlier courses in which matrix theory and quadratic forms were prominent. Roughly speaking, the transition occurred during the 1950s and 1960s, at least in U.S. universities.